# Explanation of finding length of a string in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, strlen

// Program to find the length of a string in c++ explanation?

```
int main() {
    char name[] = "computer applications";
    char *cptr = name;
    while(*cptr != '\0') {
        cptr++;
    }
    cout << "length = " << cptr - name << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your question? (Isn't it you who has to provide the explanation? ...assuming this is homework.)

Comment: If I would be able to answer why I post this question. I confuse how cptr - name is giving length

Comment: This is a quite basic thing which should be mentioned in every (serious) intro to C++...

Answer (score 3):

A string is a sequence of characters terminated by the zero terminating character `'\0'`.

For example if you will initialize a character array with the string literal "Hello" like

```
char s[] = "Hello";
```

then this declaration is equivalent to

```
char s[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
```

So the length of the string is calculated as the number of characters until the terminating zero character is encountered. When it is encountered it means that the expression `*cptr` contains the character and the loop interrupts its iterations. The difference between these two pointers `cptr - name` gives the length of the string.

According to the C++ Standard (C++14, 5.7 Additive operators)

> 5 When two pointers to elements of the same array object are
> subtracted, the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two
> array elements. The type of the result is an implementation-defined
> signed integral type; this type shall be the same type that is defined
> as std::ptrdiff_t in the  header (18.2). As with any other
> arithmetic overflow, if the result does not fit in the space provided,
> the behavior is undefined. **In other words, if the expressions P and
> Q point to, respectively, the i-th and j-th elements of an array
> object, the expression (P)-(Q) has the value i − j provided the value
> fits in an object of type std::ptrdiff_t.** Moreover, if the
> expression P points either to an element of an array object or one
> past the last element of an array object, and the expression Q points
> to the last element of the same array object, the expression
> ((Q)+1)-(P) has the same value as ((Q)-(P))+1 and as -((P)-((Q)+1)),
> and has the value zero if the expression P points one past the last
> element of the array object, even though the expression (Q)+1 does not
> point to an element of the array object. Unless both pointers point to
> elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the
> array object, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: perhaps worth mentioning that `s` is a statically sized array and `std::size(s)` [can be used in this particular example](https://godbolt.org/z/8nPEr1)

Comment: I want to know how cptr - name is giving length integer. How this difference working.

Comment: @KavirajPandey According to the pointer arithmetic the result of difference of two pointers that point to elements of the same array is the number of elements of the array that are between these two pointers. See my updated post.